# Why does loop miss checking condition

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a small loop for turtle to turn at 90 degrees after meeting the corner of the square. The first loop is fine but Python seem to forget to check condition at the next loop.

I start to draw at

```
t.setpos(-300,300)
```

This work fine for the first loop:

```
for i in range(4):
t.forward(600)
print(t.pos())
if t.pos() > (300,300):
    t.right(90)
elif t.pos() > (300,-300):
    t.right(90)
elif t.pos() > (-300, -300):
    t.right(90)
elif t.pos() > (-300,300):
    t.right(90)
```

But when I increase `range()` to 5, the code forgets to check the `elif t.pos() > (-300,300):` to `t.right(90)` but instead Python continues to draw `t.forward(600)` to this position:

> (-300.00,900.00)

```
for i in range(5):
t.forward(600)
print(t.pos())
if t.pos() > (300,300):
    t.right(90)
elif t.pos() > (300,-300):
    t.right(90)
elif t.pos() > (-300, -300):
    t.right(90)
elif t.pos() > (-300,300):
    t.right(90)
```

Any idea why Python forgets to check a condition like this? Somehow I feel like I did wrong somewhere.

Comment: How exactly do you expect `if t.pos() > (300,300)` to behave?

Comment: Whatever the case, that code will never execute the `elif t.pos() > (-300,300):` block, because any value that is not greater than `(-300, -300)` will also not be greater than `(-300, 300)`.

Comment: I wanted it to check if it was run over `(300,300)` or not, if it equal to `(300,300)`, they should `t.right(90)`
Because I have tried the comparison `==` way to those corners position and python is already forgot to check the second step is `(300, -300)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seemingly easy fix is this comparision is backward:

```
elif t.pos() > (-300, 300):
```

it should be:

```
elif t.pos() < (-300, 300):
```

The reason you don't see it in the `range(4)` case is the loop quits before ever executing it.  In the `range(5)` case it finally executes and the inverted comparision causes the failure.

However, there are significant problems with this code which will show up as you build upon it. Although your debugging `print(t.pos())` statement shows:

```
(300.00,300.00)
(300.00,-300.00)
(-300.00,-300.00)
(-300.00,300.00)
(-300.00,900.00)
```

What's really happening is:

```
(300.0, 300.0)
(300.00000000000006, -300.0)
(-299.99999999999994, -300.00000000000006)
(-300.00000000000006, 299.99999999999994)
(-300.00000000000017, 900.0)
```

The reason you don't see this, is because `t.pos()` doesn't return a generic `tuple`, it returns a specialization of `tuple` called `Vec2D` which has it's own `repr()` method which masks the floating point fuzziness, by only showing two digits of precision:

```
 def __repr__(self):
        return "(%.2f,%.2f)" % self
```

You might expect your clauses to fire in order, but they don't:

Position: `(300.0, 300.0)`

trips the second clause: `elif t.pos() > (300,-300):`

position: `(300.00000000000006, -300.0)`

trips the first clause: `if t.pos() > (300,300):`

position: `(-299.99999999999994, -300.00000000000006)`

trips the third clause: `elif t.pos() > (-300, -300):`

and positions:

```
(-300.00000000000006, 299.99999999999994)
(-300.00000000000017, 900.0)
```

don't trip any of the clauses.  Add some `print()` statements to convince yourself of this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, it might not be efficient but it work, somehow...

```
if myturtle[count].xcor() > 300 and myturtle[count].heading() == 0:
   myturtle[count].right(90)
if myturtle[count].ycor() < -300 and myturtle[count].heading() == 270:
   myturtle[count].right(90)
if myturtle[count].xcor() < -300 and myturtle[count].heading() ==180:
   myturtle[count].right(90)
if myturtle[count].ycor() > 300 and myturtle[count].heading() == 90:
   myturtle[count].right(90)
```

Comment: This is  a nice solution to get around the glitches with more generic tests.  However, shouldn't you be able to express the last three clauses as `elif`?

Comment: I have just realize this solution is only work with a square so it might be bad for me if I want to change the number of corners beside 4.